# GDB on ARM: cannot access memory at address when single stepping

Tags: gdb, arm

I'm trying to debug ARM program with gdb, In the first few instructions `stepi` works, for some reason in the 5th instruction I get an error `Cannot access memory at address 0x908` when trying to single step, what might be the problem?

```
16: x6/i 0x12af0
   0x12af0: sub r12,pc,#28
   0x12af4: ldm r12 {r1,r2,r10,r11,lr}
   0x12af8: add r10,r10,r12
   0x12afc: add r11,r11,r12
=> 0x12b00: mov r0,r2
   0x12b04: sub r9,r12,r1

(gdb) stepi
Cannot access memory at address 0x908
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> what might be the problem?

Looks like a bug in GDB (it probably decided to switch into Thumb mode for some reason).

You didn't say what version of GDB you are using. In any case, try a newer GDB build.